# LINQ Where(), what to do if I need to get everything?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Consider the next example:

```
public List<Allergy> GetAllergies(int? ingredientId = null)
{
    var allergies = new List<Allergy>();

    var preSelect = ingredientId != null
     ? _dataContext.Ingredients.Where(x=> x.Id == ingredientId).SelectMany(x=>x.Allergies.AsQueryable())  
     : _dataContext.Allergies.AsQueryable();

    preSelect.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        var a = Mapper.Map<Database.Allergy, Allergy>(x);
        allergies.Add(a);
    });

    return allergies;
}
```

That works, but I believe it's possible to get rid of null checking part and get all Ingredients if `ingredientId` is null right there in `Where()` body. How can we do that? Also any other suggestions to improve this piece of code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var preSelect = 
    _dataContext
    .Ingredients
    .Where
    (
        x=> (!ingredientId.HasValue || x.Id == ingredientId)
    )
    .SelectMany(x=>x.Allergies.AsQueryable());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  You can think of the where clause as an `if` statement.

```
_dataContext.Ingredients.Where( x => x.Id != null && x.Id == ingredientId)
```

(Assuming `x.Id` is also of type `int?`)

Comment: `x => x.Id == null || x.Id == ingredientId`  or `x => !(x.Id != null && x.Id != ingredientId)` I would think.  (I added the second form because Resharper sometimes complains about the first, heh.)